# PHP and multiple inheritance; I know you can't, but then how do I..?

Tags: php, oop, dependencies, multiple-inheritance, composition

I understand that [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem)<sup>1</sup> is simply not supported in PHP, and while many "hacks" or workarounds exist to emulate it, I also understand that an approach such as [object composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) is likely more flexible, stable, and understandable than such workarounds. Curiously, PHP's 5.4's [traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) will be the fitting solution, but we're not quite there yet, are we.

Now, this isn't simply an "*amidoinitrite?*" question, but I'd like to ensure that my approach makes sense to others.

Given I have classes `Action` and `Event` (*there are more, but we'll keep it brief*) and they both require (*near*) identical methods, the obvious approach would be; create a common base class, extend and go; they are, after all, conceptually similar enough to constitute being siblings in a class hierarchy (*I think*)

The problem is `Event` needs to extend a class (*`Exception`*) that itself cannot extend anything. The methods (*and properties*) all pertain to "attribute" values, we'll call them "options" and "data", where "options" are values stored at class level, and "data" are values stored at instance level.

With exception of (*no pun intended*) the `Exception` class, I can simply create a common class that all pertinent objects extend in order to inherit the necessary functionality, but I'm wondering what I can do to avoid the seemingly inevitable code duplication in `Event`; also, other classes that are not conceptually similar enough to be siblings need this functionality.

So far the answer seems to be, using the object composition approach, create a `Data` class, and manage it at two points:

- At object instantiation, create a `Data` instance to be used with the object as "data".
- At some point (*through a static `initialize()` method perhaps*) create a `Data` instance to be used statically with the class as "options".

Interfaces, named `IData` and `IOption` for example, would be implemented by classes needing this functionality. `IData` simply enforces the instance methods of the `Data` class on the consumer, and calls would be forwarded to the instance `Data` property object, whereas `IOption` would enforce similarly named methods (*substitute "data" for "option"*) and those methods would forward to the static `Data` property object.

What I'm looking at is something like this (*the methods are somewhat naive in appearance, but I've slimmed them for brevity here*):

```
interface IData{

    public function setData($name, $value);

    public function putData($name, &$variable);

    public function getData($name = null);

}

interface IOption{

    public static function initializeOptions();

    public static function setOption($name, $value);

    public static function setOptions(Array $options);

    public static function getOptions($name = null);

}

class Data implements IData{

    private $_values = array();

    public function setData($name, $value){
        $this->_values[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function putData($name, &$variable){
        $this->_values[$name] = &$variable;
    }

    public function getData($name = null){
        if(null === $name){
            return $this->_values;
        }
        if(isset($this->_values[$name])){
            return $this->_values[$name];
        }
        return null;
    }

}

class Test implements IData, IOption{

    private static $_option;
    private $_data;

    public static function initializeOptions(){
        self::$_option = new Data();
    }

    public static function setOption($name, $value){
        self::$_option->setData($name, $value);
    }

    public static function setOptions(Array $options){
        foreach($options as $name => $value){
            self::$_option->setData($name, $value);
        }
    }

    public static function getOptions($name = null){
        return self::$_option->getOptions($name);
    }

    public function __construct(){
        $this->_data = new Data();
    }

    public function setData($name, $value){
        $this->_data->setData($name, $value);
        return $this;
    }

    public function putData($name, &$variable){
        $this->_data->putData($name, $variable);
        return $this;
    }

    public function getData($name = null){
        return $this->_data->getData($name);
    }

}
```

So where do I go from here? I can't shake the feeling that I'm moving away from good design with this; I've introduced an irreversible dependency between the client classes and the storage classes, which the interfaces can't explicitly enforce.

---

**Edit**: Alternatively, I could keep the reference to `Data` (*wherever necessary*) public, eliminating the need for proxy methods, thus simplifying the composition. The problem then, is that I cannot deviate from the `Data` class functionality, say for instance if I need to make `getData()` act recursively, as this snippet exemplifies:

```
function getData($name = null){
    if(null === $name){
        // $parent_object would refer to $this->_parent
        // in the Test class, given it had a hierarchal
        // implementation
        return array_replace($parent_object->getData(), $this->_values);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Of course, this all boils down to separate definitions on a per-class basis, to support any deviation from a default implementation.

I suppose the end-all here, is that I'm having trouble understanding where code duplication is "alright" (*or more accurately, unavoidable*) and where I can extract common functionality into a container, and how to reference and use the contained functionality across classes, deviating (*typically negligibly*) where necessary. Again, traits (*in my cursory testing on beta*) seem to be a perfect fit here, but the principle of composition has existed long before 5.4 (*and PHP entirely for that matter*) and I'm certain that there is a "classic" way to accomplish this.

---

<sub>1. Interestingly, the page for [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) at Wikipedia has been flagged for copyright investigation. Diamond problem seemed like a fitting substitute.</sub>

Comment: The real question is, is it worth it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I think I know what you're getting at, but care to elaborate? (*short answer; yes, I think it is if it saves me keystrokes and centralizes otherwise duplicate code, but I'm open to influence*)

Comment: Whatever marginal benefit you get from this will be swamped by the obscurity you introduce.  The developer coming after you will go *"What is this I don't even..."*

Comment: @RobertHarvey - That is, in addition to dependency introduction, my concern. I'm just not sure how else to go about this, besides just going "copypasta!" and duplicating methods where necessary (*or going outside to enjoy the fresh autumn air until 5.4 becomes readily available*)

Comment: You will one day (probably through much pain like myself), find that composition scales better than any type of inheritance will over time.  Inheritence is also flawed on the basis that not every taxonomy can be represented adequately with a simple hierarchy.  Great example of this here: http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/ch2-Z-G-67.gif

Comment: Thanks @ChrisSmith - Yea, I'm finding that faster and faster. This example is such that not all of the proposed sibling classes should be siblings; which of course is why inheritance is not the answer here. Composition is definitely the way to go; however even composition may not be the solution, as each class (*for the instance methods at least*) varies significantly enough to warrant their own definitions. This is really unfortunate, because there's so much potential for centralization of otherwise duplicate code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I've just read your question again and you seem to be suggesting that you are actually using the getters and setters to manipulate the data. If this is the case then could you provide me with more detail on what it is that you're trying to achieve. I suspect that how you've decided to model your objects and data is what has led you to this situation and that an alternative would solve the problem.

You don't need  multiple inheritance. You don't even need most of the code you've written.

If the purposes of classes 'Data' and 'Option' is to simply store data then use an array. Or, if you prefer the syntax of an object cast the array to an object or an instance of stdClass:

```
$person = (object)array(
    'name' => 'Peter',
    'gender' => 'Male'
);

OR

$person = new stdClass;
$person->name = 'Peter';
$person->gender = 'Male';
```

Having a whole bunch of getters and setters that don't actually do anything to the data are pointless.

Comment: Thanks @PeterHorne - Agreed, naive getters and setters are code bloat, but I've slimmed them for brevity (*ironically the question is long enough itself*) The getters do a bit of recursion, as the objects are tree nodes (*I'll edit with the full implementation*) but I suppose my question could be specified to the static "option" methods. Since nearly every class has options that can be set statically, is there a way (*excluding inheritance, as I've realized it's inappropriate for this use*) to share the functions across classes without traits? (*I'm impatiently awaiting 5.4*)

Comment: I'm not aware of any workarounds for the lack of traits in < 5.4, but a different approach to modelling your objects may sidestep the issue completely. If you're happy to share your code then I'd be happy to take a look at a pastebin of the relevant sample.

Comment: Alright @PeterHorne - As I mentioned, I'm more concerned with the static members now (*the instance members vary enough between classes that it's likely simpler to just duplicate the methods as necessary*) since the static members need not change **at all** between classes. Again, this issue is seemingly exemplary of one that should be solved with traits; anyways, here's the pastebin http://pastebin.com/y3Tzq9cu - this is likely a common design issue. I was thinking of making a public facing object to encapsulate this functionality in each object; but then it needs to be initialized.

Comment: I've split the class into two distint classes: a class which manages Options, and a class that performs a function which is influenced by the settings of the Options class. Pass the options class as a dependency into the second class and problem solved. You could pass the same Options object to multiple instances of multiple classes, or make use of different instances of the Options class. http://pastebin.com/QcRDmums

Comment: Thanks @PeterHorne - That's sort of the direction that I'm going; the issue is the class-wide static options object and initialization. In practice, the instance options (*array*) are passed to pertinent methods (*existing for only the life of the method invocation*), which override the class options, which override the class defaults, and are used accordingly. At the end of a each class definition file, I could call a static method to set the static options/defaults object; it's unfortunate that static members can't initialize to complex types in PHP, as that would solve the problem too.